# Heroku: edit files of a python library that is already installed

Tags: heroku

Is it possible to edit the files of a python library that is already installed within a heroku environment? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the folder where the app is installed on heroku, but I don't you can edit them. You won't have access to a text editor. See these commands:

```
heroku run bash

~ $ pwd
/app

~ $ ls
...

~ $ vi foobar.txt
bash: vi: command not found

~ $ nano foobar.txt
bash: nano: command not found
```

Comment: Not the app itself. I can manage those files. I am talking about the files of the libraries that were installed within the environment, separate and apart from the app itself.

Comment: Oh, hmm. I guess you'll have to place your library inside your app folder in that case (instead of providing only the dependency/requirements in a file). And change the import paths in code files where the library is included to link to the local library directory instead. Which language are you using?

Comment: I am using python.

Comment: Ok, so you'll have to either remove the library from requirements.txt, and copy it locally, or override the method you're using from the library in your code in some way. Editing lib files on Heroku isn't good at all, because it'll get overwritten everytime you redeploy.

Comment: Nitin, can you please explain to me how to copy it locally? how to install the library other than via requirements and the code be able to find the dependency within Heroku? I am not being able to visualize these steps.

Comment: If it's a very small library, you can just move it as is into your code and use the proper import paths. Something big like Celery would be difficult to manouver with, but I guess most good big libraries would give override options for various methods... This will be a long tutorial! maybe ask another StackOverflow question, or do some google searching. Someone else might have a better answer for your.